# 404 issues and redirect/.htaccess

Tags: 404

When I type mydomain.dev/blahwrongurl - for some reason .htaccess doesn't redirect to the 404.html file, but just write the blahwrong url out on the page and nothing else?

I get the feeling that I messed up routes somewhere, but I deactivated all of my plugins but nothing changed.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you defining custom routes? Have you modified the stock Craft `.htaccess` file?  Have you defined a custom 404.html/.twig file?

Comment: I've remove any custom routes, I've deactivated all plugins and haven't changed anything in the .htaccess file. Still same problem.

Comment: You can see an example here http://www.husetsforsikring.dk/blah

Comment: Weird... have you defined a 404.html file in your templates folder?

Comment: Yes I have and it works when I use husetsforsikring.dk/404.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you're seeing the the generic webserver 404 error page... which means there's something wrong with your server config, as its not sending 404's to Craft to handle.